# My WordPress site when down after installing a plugin and now all I get is a simple white screen

Tags: plugins, php

I've contacted my service provider and was told there is a backup available but the last one dates back to August 5th - one week ago! All the work I've done the past week will be lost. I've enabled the debug function and received this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /home/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3629

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_die() in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php:233 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(152): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false) #1 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(57): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #2 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #3 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 233

Anyone know what this means or how I can fix this without losing anything? The site was due to be finished for my client by Monday and I'm not familiar with anything PHP related. I've already tried renaming all of my folders to try and find the problem to no avail. Please, someone help - I've been desperately trying to find the problem since yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try and replace the original WP core files? (Just download the zip, extract and overwrite existing files.) Which plugin install caused this?

Comment: @kero The Divi Mobile plugin caused this, I believe. Just after I installed it, everything crashed. Which core files do you mean?

Comment: The WordPress core. Download the original version again and just replace WordPress' files for now. Then try to remove the divi mobile plugin via FTP and see if it gets better.

Comment: if you have access to the file/ folders just rename the plugin folder, add `1` to the end of the plugin name, that will disable it the next time to go to your site

Comment: @kero I will try and replace all the files to see what happens. Thanks. I've tried removing and renaming the theme and plugins in question already. Nothing worked.

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_die()" sounds more like a corrupted WP than plugin doing bad things. If that doesn't work, you should try to get a professional to look at this at short notice. (I'm voting to close the question as "too localized" now, sorry but in my opinion it is not a good fit for this site.)

Comment: @kero OK. Thank you for your help. I'll see what I can do by replacing files.

Comment: If this happened after installing a plugin, why don't you go into your ftp into wp-content > plugins and delete the folder of the new plugin.

Comment: @kero Fixed! Thank you for your help! I compared the two functions.php file and compared the differences. I then replaced the old with the new version and it started turning and then eventually came up after a few minutes. Thank you again.

Comment: can you post the answer as an answer? Comments are for clarifying questions

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! Thank you all for your help! I compared the two functions.php file and compared the differences. I then replaced the old with the new version and it started turning and then eventually came up after a few minutes. Thanks again!